# Weird error message in Xcode 4.3 with LLDB

Tags: objective-c, ios, debugging, xcode4, lldb

I am currently writing an iOS app with Xcode 4.3.2. In most parts of my code, debugging with LLDB works just fine. However at some point I am getting a strange message while stepping through my code. When I hover over an iVar, it says

> Error [IRForTarget]: Couldn't find Objective-C indirect ivar symbol OBJC_IVAR_$_MyFancyClass.iVar

instead of showing me the value. However, in the `Variables View`, I can see it just fine. Until I'm selecting `Print Description of ...` that is, because then, Xcode crashes...
When I use GDB, the hovering works but the type and values of the variable are wrong.

I recon that there is something wrong with my code which in turn causes the debuggers to fail. However, the code runs fine.  I'd love to provide some samplecode but the class is rather long and I can't pinpoint the exact location of my screwup. So has anybody encountered a similar behavior?

**UPDATE:** Actually, it seems as if this happens everywhere in my code, not just in some specific files. If it helps, while LLDB show the above message, GDB always shows an object of the Class that is owning the iVar, instead of the iVar itself.
It looks as if there is something wrong with the memory management. For example, if I say something like

```
[notificationCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(foo) name:bar object:objA];
```

the selector is invoked even when I have

```
[notificationCenter postNotificationName:bar object:objB];
```

Comment: Your code may be long, but it doesn't seem like enough people have encountered this. Can u just show a summarized version of some code where this behavior occurs?

Comment: Well, since it happens absolutely everywhere in my Code, I really don't know what I could post...

Comment: I'm just guessing here so I'm not posting an answer, but what happens if you try using the debugger console and print the object out using "po"? Also, do you perhaps have any sort of special gdb configuration fie in place? Is this an included library that you're trying to debug? Are you building with debug information enabled? Double check your build settings (generate debug symbols, optimization level, debug information format).

Comment: Matej, you actually got it :) I already checked the settings but I did it again and noticed that "Deployment Postprocessing" was set to YES for Debug-Mode. Changing it to NO removes the warning and although I'm not quite sure if LLDB runs all smooth now (will have to check the settings more carefully), this definitely answers my question. It's a pity, that I just wasted a TSI on the matter :) So feel free to formulate a proper answer in order to collect your reward :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The cause of this error are incorrect build settings, as indicated by the discussion in the question post comments. This can be fixed by setting "Deployment Postprocessing" back to NO for Debug-Mode (the default value).

Answer (score 2):

Make sure `MyFancyClass.m` is added to your Target

Answer (score 0):

Your selector that the nsnotification is being sent to needs to have one (and only one) argument, which is an NSNotification. So when you do this:

```
[notificationCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(foo) name:bar object:objA];

-(void)foo
{

}
```

...you need to be doing this:
    [notificationCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(foo:) name:bar object:objA];

```
-(void)foo:(NSNotification *)notification
{

}
```

Notice the colon in the selector for the notificationCenter, and the argument for foo.

Comment: Correct. However, that was just me, having a typo in my pseudo-code. Remember, the real problem are the weird debugger warnings :)

Comment: (NSNotification)notification
 should be
(NSNotification*)notification