# Objective-C XCode 4.5.2 UITableViewController gets crashed

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Weird error message in Xcode 4.3 with LLDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983192/weird-error-message-in-xcode-4-3-with-lldb)

I'm trying to parse a json and targeted to a UITableView after running getting this error:

```
Error [IRForTarget]: Couldn't find Objective-C indirect
ivar symbol OBJC_IVAR_$_UITableView._headerFooterNibMap
```

Debugging but i could not find any reliable fix.

Edit:

I traced the code and see that it gives me that error on initWithNibName method

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
       self.title = NSLocalizedString(@tabBarTitle, @tabBarTitle);
       self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@tabBarIcon];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: 1. Your strings aren't in double-quotes.  Is this a paste error? If not, try putting all three of them in `"`. 2. I wouldn't use `self` in an initialiser, use the ivar (`_title` and `_tabBarItem`) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right. Thanks for your all attention guys.

I just remove the `view` outlet from the xib file and then add a `tableview` and delegate that. Then recompile the code and error was removed. It works fine right now.