# how to retrieve a NSArray from a custom class

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I have a custom class which has a integer as a variable.

```
// addons.h

-(NSMutableArray *) goodDirections:(int)iNumber;


// addons.m

-(NSMutableArray *) goodDirections:(int)iNumber;
{
    NSString *gOne = @"one"+iNumber;
    NSString *gTwo = @"two"+iNumber;
    NSString *gThree = @"three"+iNumber;
    NSString *gFour = @"four"+iNumber;
    NSMutableArray *goodValues = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:gOne,gTwo,gThree,gFour,nil];
    return goodValues;
}


// ViewController.m

addons *directions =[[addons alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *helloTest = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
helloTest = [directions goodDirections:3];
NSString *obj1 = [helloTest objectAtIndex:1];
NSLog(@"%@",obj1);
```

and the custom class has a variable number, when entered returns an array with 4 string values, how do I retrieve the values from the array in my implementation file viewController.m

Comment: `NSMutableArray *arr = [theObject simpleMethod:4];`?

Comment: It's not at all clear what you want to accomplish.  I suggest you make this more specific, else our friends down there will be the best quality of answer you can hope to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you import the custom class in the file you want.Then

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [theObject simpleMethod:4];
```

To retrieve any object in arr, you can use objectAtIndex function (for example):

```
NSString *item = [arr objectAtIndex:1];
```

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983192/weird-error-message-in-xcode-4-3-with-lldb

Comment: Why alloc / init an array? Seems a waste.

Comment: didnt get anything out of the link

Answer (score 0):

please! try below code snip

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [theObject simpleMethod:4];
obj = [arr objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: says use os undeclared identifier

Comment: (lldb) this is the error i get for
  
 NSMutableArray *helloTest = [theObject simpleMethod:3];
    NSString *obj1 = [helloTest objectAtIndex:1];
    NSLog(@"%@",obj1);

Answer (score -1):

You can use array object at index.

```
   NSMutableArray *arrayTemp = [self simpleMthod:2];
   objTemp = [arrayTemp objectAtIndex:0];
```

Or You can use

```
    for (int i=0; i<[arrayTemp count]; i++)
    {
       objTemp = [arrayTemp objectAtIndex:i];
    }
```

Comment: How is this not just `-lastObject`?

Comment: @CodaFi lastobject gives only last object from array, If we need to check all values then we need to use for loop.

Comment: That's all well and good, but tell me how iterating through an array and assigning literally the last object to that temporary is any different from calling `-lastObject`.  This is not an answer to his question, in fact, even I don't know what his question is.

Comment: @CodaFi it's right, beside the obscure question, the code presented above is kind of pointless and idempotent to just `objTemp = [arrayTemp lastObject]`