# Error [IRForTarget] in UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am having more than a table view in a view controller, it is giving error. I have no idea what is where going wrong can anyone guide. Data is not showing in table view but array has data when printed in console, i tried without array also providng static data to cell.textLabel.text, but not showing in tableview, numbers of rows checked no issue there. control does not go to cell.textLabel.text, i am not getting what is wrong. Please guide for the above. Below is the code:

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell;

if(tableView == self.mLocationTable)
{
    cell = [self.mLocationTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    else{
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    // if([self.mLocShowArr count]!= 0)
    // {
    //  NSString *str = [self.mLocShowArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = @"locations";
    // NSLog(@"show loc:%@", [self.mLocShowArr objectAtIndex:0]);
    //  }

}

if(tableView == self.mNotifyTable)
{
    cell = [self.mNotifyTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    UIImage *yourImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"emma-watson-02.jpg"];
    UIImageView *imageViewToPutInCell = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:yourImage];
    imageViewToPutInCell.frame = CGRectMake(5, 8, 55, 55);

    UILabel *cellTextLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(68, 10, 200, 40)];
    cellTextLabel.text = @"notification view";

    [cell addSubview:imageViewToPutInCell];
    [cell addSubview:cellTextLabel];

}
}
```

This is the complete error : Error [IRForTarget]: Call to a symbol-only function 'objc_msgSend' that is not present in the target.

Answer (score 0):

Things to check.

1. Data source methods all required implemented
2. `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section` 
   log the return value and make sure it is not 0
3. Give the different cell identifier for different tables
4. Make sure table data source and delegates are connected in the nib

Error Explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983192/weird-error-message-in-xcode-4-3-with-lldb)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code !!! In your code you missed "return cell;"

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
    if(tableView == self.mNotifyTable) {
      cell.textLabel.text = @"locations";

      UIImage *yourImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"emma-watson-02.jpg"];
      UIImageView *imageViewToPutInCell = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:yourImage];
      imageViewToPutInCell.frame = CGRectMake(5, 8, 55, 55);

      UILabel *cellTextLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(68, 10, 200, 40)];
      cellTextLabel.text = @"notification view";

      [cell addSubview:imageViewToPutInCell];
      [cell addSubview:cellTextLabel];
   }
   return cell;
}
```

Hope this solves your problem !!!

Accept the answer if it helps you !!!